# Retrive Images from Specific folder from google drive or one drive

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

i want to load my slider of image which image comes from google drive or one drive. i used below code for google drive but it returns all the files and i want to get from specific folder.

```
GoogleConnect.ClientId = "xxxxxx";
GoogleConnect.ClientSecret = "xxxxxx";
GoogleConnect.RedirectUri = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Split('?')[0];
GoogleConnect.API = EnumAPI.Drive;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["code"]))
{
    string code = Request.QueryString["code"];
    string json = GoogleConnect.Fetch("me", code);
    GoogleDriveFiles files = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<GoogleDriveFiles>(json); // This will returns the files      
}
else if (Request.QueryString["error"] == "access_denied")
{
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Access denied.')", true);
}
```

Comment: check the files list q command you can search for the files that you want.

Comment: hey i want images from specific folder. so is it possible to do with q command ? because no idea for q command

Comment: You might have tried to read the documentation. Q is for search as in search for files in a directory of type image